# Fan set to OFF but face fan position still ON

Tags: toyota, camry

I purchased a 2013 Toyota Camry with 46000 miles and I have noticed that I am not able to turn off face fan OFF. See the below picture. Fan is set to OFF but still face fan light is ON. I cannot turn it OFF.

- Car ignition ON, Stationary and fan knob is in OFF position -- It is
  not blowing air.
- Car ignition ON and moving on the road and fan knob is in OFF
  position -- It is blowing hot or cold air towards my face based on
  the temperature control knob setting.

[image]

Comment: With the car stationary, is air coming out of the vents towards your face? In this model, one of the four "directional" LEDs might always be illuminated, even when the fan is not running.

Comment: @David yes, it blows little air towards my face even when fan knob is in OFF position.

Comment: And the car is stationary, that is, not moving over the roadway?

Comment: @David I just sat in the car, while car ignition turned ON and stationary and it is not blowing air. It is blowing air only when it is moving.

Comment: If no air moves when the car's engine is running and the car stationary, then the fan isn't running (that is, it's off) even though the LED is illuminated.

Comment: @David then what could be the reason that fan is running even though it is set to OFF position when car is moving?

Comment: When the car moves, air outside the car is gathered in the higher-pressure area in front of the windshield, passes down through the air ducts, and is pushed into the passenger compartment without help from the fan.

Comment: @David it blows air when car is running but not when stationary. I cannot guess why it is doing that..

Comment: What do you mean by "car is running?" I asked you what was happening when the engine was running but the car itself was not moving over the roadway. You said in that condition, that air was not moving into the car's interior.

Comment: @David Car ignition ON, stationary and fan knob is in OFF position -- It is not blowing air. 
Car ignition ON and moving on the road and fan knob is in OFF position -- It is blowing hot or cold air based on the temperature control knob setting.

Comment: Yes, just as I observed: air movement into the interior of the car is dependent upon the car's moving forward over the roadway, not dependent on the fan. With no car movement, no air comes in. If the fan were on (as the LED says), then you'd have air coming in even though the car is stationary and not moving over the road. Because air only moves when the car is moving over the roadway, the fan is not operating. I don't think there's anything wrong with the fan. If the LEDs are supposed to all be off when the fan isn't running, however, then there is a fault in the switch or wiring.

Comment: It's likely that any time the ignition is ON, that one of the four LEDs will be illuminated (to show the state of the air distribution flaps in the HVAC system) even when the fan is off. What does the owner's manual say about this?

Comment: Thanks David for your time. I will look into owner’s manual. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps the manual will be helpful.

Comment: @David - Please post that as an answer, because you are spot on. This vehicle will never completely shut off its HVAC system. Air will be forced through the cabin even with the fan set to off because its how it works. Just because the fan is off doesn't mean the HVAC system is. If the OP put the system on recirculate, I'd suspect air flow would be almost completely eliminated. If they don't want air on their face, point it towards their feet. Anyway, you did great with a good answer ... just post it! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks. When the coffee hits, I'll do it.

Comment: It flows air because you do not have re circulation ON, this is outside air hitting you in the face.

Comment: Even with recirculation turned on, air will still flow through the system. Car HVAC systems are designed that way so that there's always some (albeit small) air change going on in the interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the fan isn't running, and the heating/AC system is operating as designed.

Long answer: you've confirmed that air only comes out of the vents when the car is moving forward over the ground; with the car standing still, no air moves. That demonstrates that the fan is not running, even 'though the LED over the air-distribution button is illuminated.

Air emerges from the dash vents because the car movement forward increases air pressure at the base of the windshield, which forces air down through the air ducts and into the interior. If a different air-distribution button were pushed, the air would emerge from whatever other ducts were selected. This air movement is independent of the heater fan.

It appears that the system is designed so that one of the four distribution LEDs is always on, reflecting the states of the various inside-the-system duct doors and blend flaps.

Note too that if the recirculation button is depressed, the car will continue to allow a small amount of outside air to enter the interior. That's designed-in behavior, common to all cars, to make sure there's some air change in the interior.